# Is there an equivalent of Paypal's IPN (instant payment notification) with Square Connect?

Tags: square-connect, square

I would like Square Connect to hit my URL when a new payment occurs, similar to Paypal's IPN. I couldn't find this simple but very useful use case description in SC docs, are there plans to implement it? All my app needs is a request on a URL I would provide, and then my app can use SC to pull latest order.